# How JHipster rename resources files

Tags: maven, yeoman, jhipster

I'm using [JHipster](http://jhipster.github.io/) in a project and would like to know how it renames resources files as javascript and image for caching in web browser. I didn't found any maven configuration for doing this.
I would like to know this because when it generates a production war my main image file is renamed, so this is difficulting reference the image url in email's html. Perhaps I can reference the new name in Java source.

Comment: This is not performed by Maven but by the client-side builder/optimizer, Grunt (more details [on the project's page](http://jhipster.github.io/production.html)). Hopefully this will be enough to get you started, but it looks like your underlying problem could be a tough nut to crack.

Comment: At least is a start :)

Comment: The images get compressed with a grunt task (imagemin). You could comment this task in your Gruntfile.js.